# TreeMap construtor

Tags: java

I'm having some problems with TreeMap constructors. I have a class with 2 `TreeMap<String, Client>` inside it. A tree sorted by name and another sorted by number.(Client class : String name, int number, ...)

```
private TreeMap<String, Client> nameTree;
private TreeMap<Integer, Client> numberTree;
```

How do I build the constructors for this class? So far I wrote this:

```
public ManagerTreeMap(){
        nameTree = new TreeMap<String, Client>(new StringComparator()); 
        numberTree  = new TreeMap<Integer, Client>(new IntegerComparator()); 
    }
```

My major problem is the construtor "TreeMap(Comparator c)". Can i write two comparators? if not what do I have to do?

```
    public ManagerTreeMap(Comparator<String> cp){
       nameTree = new TreeMap<String, Client>(cp);          
    }

    public ManagerTreeMap(Comparator<Integer> cpt){
       nameTree = new TreeMap<Integer, Client>(cpt); 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you don't need custom comparators.

```
public ManagerTreeMap(){
    nameTree = new TreeMap<String, Client>(); 
    numberTree  = new TreeMap<Integer, Client>(); 
}
```

Comment: Not for simple types like String and Integer. If you need a case-insensitive comparator for String you can just pass in String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER to the TreeMap constructor.

Comment: @newacct: In case you want to sort by Integer keys, is it not necessary for the sake of performance to provide Comparator to treeMap's constructor ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
public ManagerTreeMap(Comparator<String> cs, Comparator<Integer> ci){
   nameTree = new TreeMap<String, Client>(cs);          
   numberTree  = new TreeMap<Integer, Client>(ci); 
}
```

Comment: In case you want to sort by Integer keys, is it necessary for the sake of performance to provide Comparator to treeMap's constructor ?

Comment: If you don't pass in a comparator, it will just use the default comparator. There should be no difference in performance (provided that the two comparators do the same thing).